# How to change server time safely for testing purposes

Tags: linux, time, testing

We have a Debian server (in a VM) running a Java application on a Tomcat server, using a Postgres database. It's a testing environment, so we can do anything we want to it.

Every once in a while, we would like to test some logic that is scheduled eg. for Friday early morning. Only, we would like to do this for example on Monday evening. **We want the server to completely think it's some other time than "now".**

What do we need to do? Can we just turn off NTP, set the system time/time zone (and perhaps reboot)?

What are some problems we might run into? Off the top of my head, DHCP leases could fail, but we don't use DHCP here.

**Edit:** a friend pointed me to the question [What consequences / implications can arise from a wrong system clock?](https://serverfault.com/questions/284638/what-consequences-implications-can-arise-from-a-wrong-system-clock). In addition to the great answers there, my question also relates to the act of changing the time on a running system.

Comment: Can't you just set up a testing VM for this purpose?

Comment: By "server" I mean a VM on a physical server. Good point, question updated.

Comment: try to find a syscall hooking thing, I suggest.

Comment: @vektor: My point is: Doing this on a production machine is a bad idea. Set up a separate VM with a testing environment and do the testing there.

Comment: @Sven and yet again, you are correct. Of course, the machine is only used for testing purposes. Question edited. Now. What happens if I start fiddling with the system time? :)